# CSS Selectors conflicting

Tags: html, css

I have two sets of radio buttons that I want to style differently. One is in a table the other is in a div. The parent is in the table the children the div.

So it looks like this

```
<td class="lblcontainer">
    <input type"radio" name="advSearch[puborpost]" value="Published">
    <input type"radio" name="advSearch[puborpost]" value="Posted">
    <div class="calChooser">
        <input type"radio" name="cal[puborpost]" value="24 Hours">
        <input type"radio" name="cal[puborpost]" value="1 Week">
    </div>
</td>
```

My css looks like this

```
td.lblcontainer input[type="radio"]{
*css values*
}
div.calChooser input[type="radio"]{
*css values*
}
```

When I open my dev tools the td.lblcontainer is being applied to the div.calChooser for all my radio buttons inside my div.

What am I missing that prevents the radio buttons in div.calChooser from bubbling up and taking the styles for td.lblcontainer?

Comment: add ".lblcontainer " before div in your CSS

Comment: The specificity appears equal so the last rule should take precedence. Can you post a [mcve] so that we can see the actual issue?

Comment: You may want to consider using the `>` combinator instead of `␣`. `td.lblcontainer>input[type=radio]` will only affect first-level children, and therefore not the ones in the `<div>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Rules that appear later in the code override earlier rules if both have the same specificity.

I presume you got `td.lblcontainer input[type="radio"]` defined later in your CSS file. Either put it above, or **instead do**

```
td.lblcontainer > input[type="radio"]{
*css values*
}

div.calChooser input[type="radio"]{
*css values*
}
```

Note the `>` selector only targets first-level children, therefore won't affect the  `input` inside your `div`.

Answer (score 1):

```
.lblcontainer input {
  /* Style all inputs inside .lblcontainer, if you have any shared styles */
}

.lblcontainer > input {
  /* Style inputs that are direct children of .lblcontainer */
}

.calChooser input {
  /* Style inputs that are children of .calChooser */
}
```

Answer (score -3):

use !important attribute in div.calChooser like

```
.calChooser input[type="radio"]{
property : value!important;
}
```

Comment: using !important is a bad practice

Comment: Don't use !important, because overriding that will require way more specificity in the future. Only use !important for testing something in the browser, or in very rare cases where it's absolutely necessary. In this case it's not needed.